# Changing Apexcharts.js Launch Animation from Bottom-Top to Left-Right

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

Is it possible to change the animation of [line chart on Apexcharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/basic/) from bottom-top to left-right when launching the chart?

[I forked this example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/KKMqqKo) and dug the docs but can't a way to do that.

```html
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

```css
#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
}
```

```js
var options = {
 
  chart: {
    height: 380,
    type: "line",
    id: "areachart-2"
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  stroke: {
    curve: "straight"
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: series.monthDataSeries1.prices
    }
  ],
  labels: series.monthDataSeries1.dates,
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    labels: {
      rotate: 0,
      formatter: function(val) {
        return dayjs(val).format('MMM YYYY')
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return dayjs(val).format('MMM YYYY')
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    x: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return dayjs(val).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
      }
    }
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var totalIncident = [151, 169, 311, 614, 840];
var ransomDemands = [18, 60, 150, 383, 555];
var forensicsCosts = [24, 33, 58, 109, 103];

var xCat = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021'];

var defaultValues = new Array(totalIncident.length).fill(null);

var totalIncidentD = [...defaultValues]
var ransomDemandsD = [...defaultValues]
var forensicsCostsD = [...defaultValues]

var options = {
    series: [{
        name: "Total Incident Costs",
        data: defaultValues
    }, {
        name: "Ransom Demands",
        data: defaultValues
    }, {
        name: "Forensics Costs",
        data: defaultValues
    }],
    colors: ['#A0CEE8', '#4060AC', '#EC6058'],
    chart: {
        height: 500,
        width: 1200,
        type: 'line',
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        },
        fontFamily: 'Raleway, sans-serif',
        animations: {
            speed: 13000,
            easing: 'linear',
            dynamicAnimation: {
                speed: 1000
            }
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val, opt) {

            if (val === null) return;

            return val + "K"

        },
    },
    stroke: {
        curve: 'straight'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ransomware',
        align: 'center'
    },
    grid: {
        row: {
            colors: ['#f3f3f3', 'transparent'],
            opacity: 0.5
        },
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'category',
        tickPlacement: 'between',
        categories: xCat,
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        labels: {
            formatter: function (value) {
                return value + "K";
            }
        },
    }        
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();

var i = 0;

var dataInterval = setInterval(function () {

    totalIncidentD[i] = totalIncident[i];

    ransomDemandsD[i] = ransomDemands[i];

    forensicsCostsD[i] = forensicsCosts[i];

    chart.updateSeries([{
        name: "Total Incident Costs",
        data: totalIncidentD
    }, {
        name: "Ransom Demands",
        data: ransomDemandsD
    }, {
        name: "Forensics Costs",
        data: forensicsCostsD
    }])

    i = i + 1;

    if (i === xCat.length) clearInterval(dataInterval)

}, 1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .apexcharts-canvas {
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="chart"></div>

</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>


</html>
```